# error while parsing Json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, parsing

This seems to be a very basic question, but it took my couple of hours as i am not much aware of javascript and jquery.

Well, i need to parse the Json string and get the value of particular key.
Json looks like: `{"currentCT":"Brijesh"}`

I tried `eval()` and `parse()` but it seems i am missing something and i am not able to trace the issue.

I tried:

```
pre.innerHTML = eval('(' + res + ')');
```

and

```
pre.innerHTML = JSON.parse(res);
```

Both are not working for me.

**Output**
Both methods returns `[object Object]`

Point out my mistake

**EDIT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function findTeacher() {
        var url = "/TemplateTest/add/findclassteacher.action?";
        var standard = document.getElementById("classes_widget");
        var val_standard = "standard="
                + standard.options[standard.selectedIndex].value;
        url = url + val_standard + "&";
        var section = document.getElementById("sections_widget");
        var val_section = "section="
                + section.options[section.selectedIndex].value;
        url = url + val_section;
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var res = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var pre = document.getElementById("holder");
                pre.innerHTML = JSON.parse(res);
                pre.innerHTML = eval('(' + res + ')');
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How are you "getting" the JSON string?

Comment: What is the exact error you can see in error console

Comment: I am getting json in response to ajax request.

Comment: Post your code!
You have 1.8k rep, you should know by now that we need all relevant information to help you solve the problem. We need your code that requests the JSON, and the __exact__ contents of the JSON.

Comment: @Cerbrus I posted the relevant code only, the json i mentioned is the one i received as response and only part of code that is included in parsing json is `eval` and `parse`. So i posted this much info only. If request is also relevant for you i will post that too.

Comment: @Teemu I tried your answer and it is working fine for me.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd forget the `eval()`. You have also to read the value, not just an object:

```
pre.innerHTML = JSON.parse(res).currentCT;
```

`JSON.parse(res)` returns an object, `innerHTML` expects a string as a value. If the assigned value is an object instead, its `toString()` method is used, which returns [object Object] in your case.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the scenario. It will help in future also.

Comment: @teemu  Can you please look into my question and help me http://stackoverflow.com/q/24078704/2118383

Answer (score -1):

try this with your code

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
    var _data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(_data.currentCT) // Brijesh
});
```

Comment: I did not downvote but I would recommend adding some explanation for the benefit of other readers.